# 'Insert into' when query sum more then zero

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm working on procedure or query, which every day checks data and when data are bigger then zero, then procedure insert another data into table.

**Example:** Every day in October I want to check

```
select
    sum(T.Amount)
from Table T
where

    T.Month = 10

union all

--check if I already insert this month
select
        -sum(T.Amount)
    from Result
    where
        T.Day = 1
        T.Month = 10
```

Until day 15 of October I get `0`. But on 15th this query return `1500`. Now I need to this number insert into another table for every previous day of October. So at end I shoud run something like:

```
insert into Result (Amount, Day, Month)
  values (1500, n, 10)
```

where N will be from 1 to 15.

Then all remaining days (from 15th to 30th) don't pass through my check query and this `1500` won't be inserted again.

**MY PROBLEM**

My main problem is, how to achieve that this insert procedure will be run only if first check query return value bigger than `0`. I will use this to create graph, which shows number I get 15th day like I get it 1st day. This means, graph will show every day `0`, but when I get on 15th some number, this graph have to shows this number from 1st day.

This is what I get, when I only run query every day:
[image]

And this is what I need:

[image]

My idea is some procedure with (`if` query) like I describe above, but I'm not sure if it is even possible or if I have to find another solution.

Comment: Please explain more clearly your structure. What does the Result and T tables look like?

Comment: Seems like you're doing stuff in a very non-rdbms/SQL way. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I need use that data to create graph and in this graph, I need to see this `Amount` from first day of month even when I get `Amount` later

Comment: And I will provide structures of tables later when I got to my PC.

Comment: @jarlh 
Okey, I reedited my question

Comment: "My idea is some procedure with (if query) like I describe above" Something like : `for select sum(t.amount) from table t where t.month = 10 into :amount do begin if (:amount > 0) then insert into Result.... end` ?

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible with a group by and a having clause.

```
INSERT INTO {tablename} <select_stmt> 

<select_stmt>   ::=  a SELECT whose result set fits the target columns
```

You have to write your select in a way returning only your desired values.

Comment: But there is a problem: Let´s say on the 5th of a month you get a value over zero (or whatever threshold value you implement), what should happen on the 6th?

Comment: I think you must delete your data first and then insert. You get 1500 on the 15th, and 2200 on the 16th ... 1500 - 2200 = -700

Comment: Ok, I still don´t understand you: You want to update Table A when in Table B the FIRST amount is stored? What if a second value occurs? Do you then want to update? What is the structure of your Table A? Only Month and amount?